# Change RSReportServer.config using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

How can i add/modify  Authentication types tag in RSReportServer.config file using PowerShell?
I have currently

```
<Authentication>  
      <AuthenticationTypes>  
         <RSWindowsNegotiate/>   
      </AuthenticationTypes>  
      <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>  
   </Authentication>
```

What i want is to add two more rows in AuthenticationTypes tag

```
<Authentication>  
      <AuthenticationTypes>  
         <RSWindowsNegotiate/>  
         <RSWindowsNTLM/>
         <RSWindowsBasic/>  
      </AuthenticationTypes>  
      <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>  
   </Authentication>
```

Comment: Step 1: query "modify xml with powershell".  Step 2: come back with what you've done when you get stuck.

Comment: Simple web search - PowerTip: Use PowerShell to Edit XML File | Scripting Blog   https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-powershell-to-edit-xml-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplistic approach given the details of the question.

```
$x = [xml](Get-Content -Path '<pathToFile>\RSReportServer.config')
$node = $x.Authentication.AuthenticationTypes
$node.AppendChild($x.CreateNode([System.Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element,'RSWindowsNTLM',$null))
$node.AppendChild($x.CreateNode([System.Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element,'RSWindowsBasic',$null))
$x.Save('<pathToFile>\RSReportServer.config')
```

You essentially select your parent node (`$node`). Use the `AppendChild()` method to add a newly created node. You can easily create a node using the `CreateNode()` method provided by the `XmlDocument` instance (`$x`).

You must use the full path to the config file when using the `Save()` method.

---

For a more dynamic approach, you can create a collection of nodes to add. Then loop through the collection and only add missing nodes to the `AuthenticationTypes` node.

```
$NodesToAdd = 'RSWindowsNegotiate','RSWindowsNTLM','RSWindowsBasic'
$x = [xml](Get-Content -Path '<pathToFile>\RSReportServer.config')
$node = $x.Authentication.AuthenticationTypes
foreach ($item in $NodesToAdd) {
    if (!$node.Item($item)) {
    $node.AppendChild($x.CreateNode([System.Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element,$item,$null))
    }
}
$x.Save('<pathToFile>\RSReportServer.config')
```

Comment: Is some easy way to determine if Element already exist in not to not append, because i don't want to insert duplicates ?

Comment: @user2171512, yes. I added a new code block that will handle that case.